# How to use observable object in wrapped textfield class

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have 4 textfields with lines underneath them all. When the user enters a number into the first textfield it jumps to the next and so on until a number it entered into the last field at that point the keyboard will just resign and the pin will be evaluated. I want to be able to change the color of the lines depending on which textfield is focused the time. 
**What I have tried**
So far I've tried making an instance of an observable object in a representable swift file that makes up my textfield. So I'll change the Observable Object when nextField becomes first responder and I'll change a state variable in my SwiftUI file. When I try to make an instance of my Observable Object in my representable file I get an error that states "Class 'SchoolCode_WrappableTextField' has no initializers". Overall I'm essentially just trying to change the color of the underline depending on which textfield is focused at the time. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
@objc func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    if (sender.text?.count)! > 0 {
        if let nextField = sender.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(sender.tag + 1) as? UITextField{

            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else{
            sender.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}`
```

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FAYa.png)